# Move all words with a specific order to the top of the list

Tags: linux, text-processing, grep, regular-expression, password

I have a password list that looks like this:

```
aaaa00
aaaa01
aaaa02
...
zzzz97
zzzz98
zzzz99
```

I want to move all words with this pattern to the beginning of the list (the text file):

**Vowel**-**Consonant**-**Vowel**-**Consonant**-***XX***

How can I do that? Thanks.

Comment: Kindly post input and output with example. so we can provide the solution asap

Answer (score 3):

Use `ex`:

```
vowel='[AaEeIiOoUu]'
cons='[BCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXYZbcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz]'
printf '%s\n' "g/^$vowel$cons$vowel$cons[0-9][0-9]\$/m 0" x | ex file.txt
```

---

Another approach, using `set ic`, also known as `set ignorecase`:

```
vow='[aeiou]'
cns="[$(printf %s {a..z} | tr -d "$vow")]"
printf '%s\n' 'set ignorecase' "g/^$vow$cns$vow$cns[0-9][0-9]\$/m 0" x | ex test.txt
```

---

These answers are [POSIX compliant](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ex.html).  The heart of each is the `g` command, which performs a certain action on each line matching a given regex.  I've used the `m`ove command to place matching lines after "line 0," which is to say, move them to the beginning of the file.

---

Incidentally, what are you doing?  A manual compilation of password types?

How about this for code golf:

```
printf %s\\n {a,e,i,o,u}{b..z}{a,e,i,o,u}{b..z}{00..99}|grep -ve^.{,..}\[eiou]
```

There, I've generated all combinations you're interested in using only 78 bytes!  :P

Answer (score 0):

To move all lines that start with vowel-not vowel-vowel-not vowel to the start of a file:

```
{ grep -i '[aeiouy][^aeiouy][aeiouy][^aeiouy]' input; grep -iv '[aeiouy][^aeiouy][aeiouy][^aeiouy]' input; } >outfile
```

If "not vowel" isn't good enough, then replace `[^aeiouy]` with your list of consonants: `[bcdf...]`.

#### Example

Consider this input file:

```
$ cat >input
asasxx
bsbsxx
esesxx
wswsxx
```

Run our command:

```
$ { grep -i '[aeiouy][^aeiouy][aeiouy][^aeiouy]' input; grep -iv '[aeiouy][^aeiouy][aeiouy][^aeiouy]' input; } >outfile
```

This is the output file:

```
$ cat outfile
asasxx
esesxx
bsbsxx
wswsxx
```

Comment: Look at the example text.  There are no literal `xx` sequences.

Comment: @Wildcard There are also no Vowel-Consonant-Vowel-Consonant sequences in his example text.  The question is ambiguous.  Without clarification from the OP, all we can do is guess.